# Nested Logit or Probit in R

Tags: r

Is there a R package for a Nested Logit or Probit model?

I've checked the bayesm and mnp packages, and they don't appear to have the capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [mlogit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=mlogit) or [VGAM](http://cran.r-project.org/package=VGAM) packages.

Web searches work well via [r-seek](http://www.rseek.org).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that I have the capacity to edit Dirk's postings (not surprising given our relative merits in R programming), but the link is actually to [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org/), not r-seek.org

Other search facilities include [Baron's site](http://search.r-project.org/) and of course Google with "r-project" in the search string:

Comment: Thanks to both of you to catch and fix that.